# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on getAttribute method

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ember.js

I have a function where I need to get the 'id' of an element in an array (county).

```
function returnCountyId(){
   var countyName = findCountyMatchFromServer();
   var foundCounty = county.findBy('title', countyName);
   var countyId = foundCounty.getAttribute('id');
   return countyId
}
```

I find the name (countyName) but somehow

```
foundCounty.getAttribute('id');
```

returns error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Rest of the code:

```
function findCountyMatchFromServer(){
   var county = getElementAsString("ddlCounty");
   return county;
};  

var county = [{
   id: '1',
   title: "Harjumaa",
   avgPrice: '1234',
   avgSurface: '23',
}, {
   id: '2',
   title: 'Hiiumaa',
   avgPrice: '5345',
   avgSurface: '243',
}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: If this is an Ember Array object, use foundCountry.get('id') as opposed to .getAttribute. .getAttribute isn't a function. Check out the docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_get

Comment: This isn't an ember object, you're going to have to use `Em.get(foundCountry, 'id')`

Comment: There is also just a simple `foundCounty.id` ...

Comment: Yes indeed there is, but that does assume that foundCountry exists, in the event where it doesn't, you've got a good ol' fashion null reference issue.

Comment: SOLVED it by replacing
var countyId = foundCounty.getAttribute('id');
with
var countyId = foundCounty.id;